# How to implement flood fill in a Pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame, lag

I would like to know a good way of filling part of a Pygame surface.
The best example of what I want is the way the paint bucket works in MS Paint.

For example, if there were a circle drawn in black on a white surface, I want to fill the white inside the circle(or whatever the shape might be).

To give you an idea of what I'm working on, I'm making a pixel art tool and I'm working on a feature similar to the bucket from MS Paint. (Watch This: [http://imgur.com/a/ogtPV](https://imgur.com/a/ogtPV))

I've tried using `Surface.get_at()` and `Surface.set_at()` a bunch to fill, but once you get around 100x100 pixels of an area to fill, it lags too much.

I'm also open to any other methods of doing it that don't lag.

Comment: @SimeonAleksov No, that would just make the whole surface whatever color I choose. Go into MS Paint and mess around with the paint bucket if you don't understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I suppose that tool in bitmap editors is called "flood fill", might be useful to know if you search for an algorithm.

Comment: As a side note, if you are serious about a pixel art tool, I recommend you use Numpy + OpenCV for all logic and Pygame only as a frontend (final array presentation and mouse/keyboard input)

Comment: @MikhailV Pygame works fine for it. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a method that takes roughly `60 ms` for a `100x100` area, and under `2000 ms` for a `1000x1000` area. Explanation in the code.

```
import random
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 640))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load('delete_image.png').convert()


def fill(surface, position, fill_color):
    fill_color = surface.map_rgb(fill_color)  # Convert the color to mapped integer value.
    surf_array = pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(surface)  # Create an array from the surface.
    current_color = surf_array[position]  # Get the mapped integer color value.

    # 'frontier' is a list where we put the pixels that's we haven't checked. Imagine that we first check one pixel and 
    # then expand like rings on the water. 'frontier' are the pixels on the edge of the pool of pixels we have checked.
    #
    # During each loop we get the position of a pixel. If that pixel contains the same color as the ones we've checked
    # we paint it with our 'fill_color' and put all its neighbours into the 'frontier' list. If not, we check the next
    # one in our list, until it's empty.

    frontier = [position]
    while len(frontier) > 0:
        x, y = frontier.pop()
        try:  # Add a try-except block in case the position is outside the surface.
            if surf_array[x, y] != current_color:
                continue
        except IndexError:
            continue
        surf_array[x, y] = fill_color
        # Then we append the neighbours of the pixel in the current position to our 'frontier' list.
        frontier.append((x + 1, y))  # Right.
        frontier.append((x - 1, y))  # Left.
        frontier.append((x, y + 1))  # Down.
        frontier.append((x, y - 1))  # Up.

    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, surf_array)


while True:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                color = random.choice(tuple(pygame.color.THECOLORS.values()))
                print('Running')
                time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                fill(image, event.pos, color)
                print('Finished in {} ms'.format(pygame.time.get_ticks() - time))

    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the image I experimented with (I'll take revenue if you try to sell the image):
[image]

Comment: I'm not selling it. I might redistribute it though. :P

Comment: @LarryMcMuffin No problem as long is not for commercial use ;)

Comment: @LarryMcMuffin I edit my answer. This method should be more the twice as fast!

Comment: @LarryMcMuffin Oh right, you need to have [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) installed. Easiest is to install it via pip.

Comment: I'm using python 3.3.3, so I am having a hard time with pip. xD

Comment: Can't find numpy for python 3.3.3.

Comment: @LarryMcMuffin What operating system are you using? Do you have pycharm as IDE?

Comment: Windows and no.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is called "flood fill". Pygame does not have built-in flood fill function. Easiest option probably would be using OpenCV library. Google "install opencv" for your platform.

Then you can wrap it in a function for Pygame surface:

```
def Fill(Surf, Point, Color):
    arr = pygame.surfarray.array3d(Surf)    # copy array from surface
    swapPoint = (Point[1], Point[0])        # swap X and Y
    cv2.floodFill(arr, None, swapPoint, Color)
    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(Surf, arr)
```

This will flood fill a connected area at a Point with Color.